# Getting data from multiple pages using incremental page number value

Tags: php

I have a script to get certain data from a page based on the content of a span ID
However there are 200+ pages of results to trawl through and it only displays 127 results on each page

The script I have does get data for the 127 elements that are on the first page however it wont then open the new page and continuing to get data
It just stops after the initial 127

Any help would be great

```
$end = 200;
$start = 1;
$stop = $start + 10;
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/res/'.$start);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $stop;
$i = 0;
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) { //Loops through all available span elements
    if (!empty($element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value)) { // Discards irrelevant span elements based on their `ID`. A similar sorting is achieved with `empty()` as the target `span` doesn't have any associated `ID`.
        echo "Record : ".$i.' '. $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value."\n"; 
        $i++;
        $end = $start;
    }
}
if($i == 127) {
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $next = $start++;
        $page = $next;
        $html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/res/'.$page);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) 
        { 
            if (!empty($element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value)) 
            { 
                echo "Record : ".$i.' '. $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value."\n"; 
                $i++;
                $end = $start;
            }
        }

    } while ($page != $stop);
    //echo $i.' Records';
}
```

Comment: in your first loop, the last record is : `"Record : 127 <the id>"` ?

Comment: Yep 127 is the last record displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, since your last record displayed in the first loop is 127, the line after that `echo` increments `$i` from 127 to 128.

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) { //Loops through all available span elements
    if (!empty($element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value)) { // Discards irrelevant span elements based on their `ID`. A similar sorting is achieved with `empty()` as the target `span` doesn't have any associated `ID`.
        echo "Record : ".$i.' '. $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value."\n"; 
        $i++; //At last iteration, $i = 128
        $end = $start;
    }
}
```

And then, `if($i == 127)` will be false.

I suggest you to change the condition to `if($i >= 127)`

Comment: Well no thats incorrect 
there are only 127 on a page 
the next page will then start again at 1 hence $i reverts back to 0 and it then opens a new url based on the new incremented page number

Comment: Then, before `if($i == 127)`, add this line : `echo "i = " . $i;`

Comment: $i can't revert back to 0 since it worth 128 when the first loop is over. the condition `if($i == 127)` will be false.

Comment: Doh ! Didnt think about that ..
Yeah changed it to > 127 and its working fine now .. many thanks :)